# Many to Many Relationship Join Query between Two Table in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

First `User` table have four columns: `id ,first_name, last_name,password`

my `Address` Table have four colmnns  `id , company_name,email , phone`

Common `Address_user` Table:

[image]

My User Model Look Like This http://pastebin.com/ntuvJ8Lj and my Address Model Look Like This

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
    'created_by',
    'company_name',
     'phone', 
     'email', 'address'
    ];
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }
    public function getAddressListAttribute()
    {
        return $this->users->lists('id');
    }
}
```

now I need the  all of address which login user is involved or connected

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alxse.png):

Comment: The link for `User` model is broken buddy

Comment: http://notepad.cc/abaneel

Comment: http://notepad.cc/abaneel this is my User Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `User.php`

Add your relation with 'address' model:

```php
public function addresses() {
        return $this->belongsToMany( Address::class, 'address_id', 'user_id' )->withTimestamps();
    }
```

You wrote right relation in your `Address.php` with `users` therefore, I'm not going to retype it here.

and please note that you don't need to write `address_id` and `user_id` because simply eloquent will predict it if you are following the convention, which you do!

But I can tell that you are not following the convention of naming your tables, if you want **Eloquent** to predict and relation between your model and your table in DB then you have to make the name of your model the singular of your table name, or vice versa, table: `users` model: `User`.

**The Gist:**

```php
$user = auth()->user(); // get logged in user

$addresses = $user->addresses()->get(); // get this user addresses. or use $user->addresses only 

// now you may loop through it and have each of your addresses.
foreach($addresses as $address){
    var_dump($address->company_name); // or perhabs ->email
}
```

Comment: @HoqueMdZahidul Welcome buddy! I hope you mark it as your answer :)

Comment: @HoqueMdZahidul add field in your user table call it `role` and store value of `USER` or `ADMIN` and in your `User.php` add constants like to const `const ROLE_ADMIN = 'ADMIN';`  `const ROLE_USER = 'USER';` and then use if on your user like so  `if($user->role == User::ROLE_ADMIN);`